# Changing SystemAccentColor Not Applied to All Elements

Tags: uwp

I am trying to make it possible to change the in-app 'theme' (color).

I'm doing this by setting the SystemAccentColor as follows:

```
public MyPage()
{
    Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush"] = AppPrimaryColourBrush;
    Application.Current.Resources["SystemAccentColor"] = AppPrimaryColourBrush.Color;
    this.InitializeComponent();
}
```

I then change AppPrimaryColorBrush elsewhere in my code, and the renavigate to MyPage.

I have the issue that this isn't applied to all elements - e.g. my ToggleSwitch background isn't reflected in the new colour, however when I mouse over the ToggleSwitch the mouseover colour is the new colour.

I have page caching disabled.

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Side issue:
I have noticed plenty of apps that manage to do this without reloading the Page (renavigating to the page). Is there a simple way to achieve this without rebinding all of the control styles to a new observable object?
(let me know if I should move this to a separate question)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not sure, but there even may be a problem that you are assigning a `Color` to a `SolidColorBrush` while assigning the `SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush`. Try assign the `AppPrimaryColourBrush` to it directly.

Comment: Thanks Marian, I picked that up before and forgot to update! The Highlight is a Brush, not a Color.